# In Excel, I want to compare each cell value with the rest of the cell values in that column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the sample excel where i have bulk deals in stock market, i want to compare each stock and want to find whether it is a "Day Trade" or not.
Can you please suggest excel formula how can cell value with rest of the cell values in that column?

For example in the below example i have "Stock" column where i am trying to compare "Reliace" cell  value with rest of the cell values in that column and updated "Result" as "Day Trade"

[image]

Comment: The question is quite hard to understand. Are you just trying to say: "how can I automate the yellow column?". If so, just tell us the logic -- is the same stock always a day trade? Is it only a day trade if it's bought and sold consecutively?

Comment: @CallumDA, I want to compare one cell value with the rest of the cells in that column to see if it is repeated or not

Comment: So if the same stock is listed multiple times, does it become "Day trade"? E.g. if TCS was listed again and in action column, it was listed as "buy" again, would it be day trade? Or only if it is both buy and sell?

Answer (score 0):

Create another sheet (e.g. Sheet2) and put "Reliance" and "HDFC" in `A1:A2`. Then in your table you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(<StockName>,Sheet2!A1:A2,0))),"Day Trade","Not Day Trade")
```

Change  with a reference to the cell with the stock name in. From your example it looks like this formula would go in cell D2 and StockName would be in B2

You can build this out, putting all of your day trade stock names in the lookup table on Sheet2, just update the reference in the formula